# how to implement similar listitem to display up to 10 images?

Tags: android, listview

I am looking for some way to implement a list item which shows up to 10 images, where first 1-2 images are large and others are small. how do i achieve it?

[image]

Comment: please look at this ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row

Comment: @sush its shows hot to display different listitems. I am looking for implementation of particular one.

Comment: sorry i got it. As per  your need as need and requirement you can show thumbnails have little transparent view with pager.

Comment: I will finish my library for exotic list realization in a few days. Check it on Github - GensaGames/LinkedListView